# Printing a PDF from another domain when I control both domains through Javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets name Domain A. Domain.com
I have domain B which is just an IP so no HTTPS.

The PDF is in domain B. Example http://8.8.8.8/my.pdf

I am opening the PDF with

`var printWindow = window.open( url, 'Print', 'left=200, top=200, width=950, height=700, toolbar=0, resizable=1');`

But when I try to use printWindow.print();  I am getting Failed to read a named property 'print' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "DomainA" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

How can I force print the window knowing I have full control of both domains and also the PC that will need to print them. This doesn´t need to work for everyone. Just for this computer.

Answer (score 1):

The same-origin policy is a browser security feature that restricts how documents and scripts on one origin can interact with resources on another origin.

An origin is defined by the scheme (also known as the protocol, for example HTTP or HTTPS), port (if it is specified), and host. When all three are the same for two URLs, they are considered same-origin. For example, http://www.example.com/foo is the same origin as http://www.example.com/bar but not https://www.example.com/bar because the scheme is different.